# Can I remove and reframe the top horizontal studs? for a TV mount

Tags: fireplace, studs

[Photos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LaTpb.jpg) (sorry too "big" to upload here)
I am working on a project to install a heavy duty robotic mantel mount. Now I have gotten the walls open I can start seeing what needs to be done.

For this mount I have very little tolerances. I will be reframing one vertical stud for sure. What I am less sure about is how to deal with this top vertical one.

This mount needs 6 inches clearance from the mantel. Which would give me a very slender mantel.

My questions are

- These are non load bearing right? If they are, I should hire a pro.
- Can I just cut away one section of horizontal beams? They will be
  replaces with a metal brack the mount comes with.
- a pair of studs can
  support 200+ lbs with leverage, or should I add a second support
  stud?

Comment: Can you upload some pictures? Also, model # of the mount?

Comment: mm860, sorry I had linked the pictures... adding them again

Comment: Pictures help a lot. Key question: Do you actually have to cut anything away? Or is this mount (like most) going to be another layer outside the studs - i.e., either in place of or on top of the drywall. Because if that's the case (and it usually is) you **add** more wood as needed, screwed into the existing studs, in order to have wood in the right locations for the mounting bracket. Alternatively, you use the existing studs as is and just slap a sheet of 1/2" plywood across the studs and mount the bracket to the plywood.

Comment: I would not assume that your wall is not load bearing. Many walls over fireplaces are load bearing. Load bearing or not, I would not be taking structure in the wall out but adding. A couple of 2x4’s are cheap you need to maintain your spacing or when you rehang Sheetrock or other wall coverings finding the studs will be problematic. Adding extra won’t hurt the strength or spacing load bearing or not. A properly anchored stud will be able to handle 200 lbs but I don’t know of many systems that have a mount so small that it would only attach to 1 stud for such a heavy load.